# Instant poweroff (software based OFF switch)

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a way to skip the standard Windows shutdown procedure and instantly poweroff a computer?

Comment: You know that that's basically equivalent to forcing a crash, right? In the sense that the computer isn't able to shut itself off properly (because doing so takes some time), and files could be corrupted when it starts up again.

Comment: Basically, yes. It sounds like a stupid idea when you put it that way, but if there was some way to control the crash...or even to force a bluescreen, it would be useful.

Comment: How to force a bluescreen, the Microsoft way: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244139

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some 3rd party programs to do it. For example, [Instant Shutdown](http://www.zazub.com/programs/instantshutdown.exe) from [Zazub](http://www.zazub.com/Software/).

> Instant Shutdown is a C++ program that
>   instantly powers off your computer
>   when run, as if it were unplugged.
>   Careful when using it, as Instant
>   Shutdown does not ask for any type of
>   confirmation, and all unsaved work
>   will be lost. Instant Shutdown does
>   not generate any Windows improper
>   shutdown error messages, so use it to
>   replace the default windows shutdown
>   option and save yourself 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the shutdown time using this registry tweak. Save the following as `shutdown.reg` and double click to export into registry. **(Please take a back up of your registry before)**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"AutoEndTasks"="1″
"HungAppTimeout"="1000″
"WaitToKillAppTimeout"="1000″

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control]
"WaitToKillServiceTimeout"="1000″

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop]
"AutoEndTasks"="1″
"HungAppTimeout"="1000″
"WaitToKillAppTimeout"="1000″
```

Comment: I saw this same script during a bit of research, but I was hoping for something sub 5 seconds (security program)